# Numpy array is not updated after each loop iteration

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I am trying to calculate some metrics for my data in a Python-loop. The metrics are irrelevant here. Important is that I calculate them for a set of data points for different thresholds. I am interested in collecting metrics per-threshold and then from all the thresholds together, therefore I compute each metric for each data point at the particular threshold, save it to a list, and then save this list in another list which I will then use in a different part of the code. So I ended up with two nested Python-loops.

What I noticed is that in each threshold-iteration I get the same metrics. However if run the same metric for a threshold separately the values are different.

Examples of threshold values with a for-loop:

```
Thr: 0.1
iou median 0.8630754827737117 
iou mean 0.8386529686837483 

Thr: 0.2
iou median 0.8630754827737117 
iou mean 0.8386529686837483 

Thr: 0.3
iou median 0.8630754827737117 
iou mean 0.8386529686837483
```

Examples of threshold values if I fixed a threshold

```
Thr: 0.1
iou median 0.8630754827737117 
iou mean 0.8386529686837483 

Thr: 0.2
iou median 0.8909001769131588 
iou mean 0.8748827498937638

Thr: 0.3
iou median 0.9528955473520166 
iou mean 0.9301409526378364
```

I assume that the value from the first iteration is somehow saved and propagated to the next iteration.
I am not sure what is happening here. Therefore I would like to ask you for the help with explaining this behavior and potentially fixing bugs in my code. My assumption was that in each threshold-iteration a new list will be created which will be destroyed at the end of the iteration but I think it is not what is actually happening.

For the sake of making sure that I removed everything from the previous iteration I set each list to an empty list and then delete it. I am not sure if it does anything. I thought that it is a problem with conversion from a list to a numpy array thus I do not save it as a local variable. I checked the iou_tmp and mse_tmp lists at the beginning of each iteration and they are empty.

```
    for t in thresholds:
        print(f"Thr: {t}")
        mse_tmp = list()
        iou_tmp = list()
        all_images = zip(all_test_images, all_generated_images)

        for test_image, generated_image in all_images:

            test_image[test_image > t] = 1.
            test_image[test_image != 1.] = 0.
            generated_image[generated_image > t] = 1.
            generated_image[generated_image != 1.] = 0.
            labels = [0., 1. ] #np.unique(test_image)
            score_iou = metrics.jaccard_score(test_image.ravel(), generated_image.ravel(), labels=labels, average='micro')
            mse_score = metrics.mean_squared_error(test_image.ravel(), generated_image.ravel())
            iou_tmp.append(score_iou)
            mse_tmp.append(mse_score)

        iou_scores.append(iou_tmp)
        mse.append(mse_tmp)
        print("iou median {} \n".format(np.median(np.array(iou_tmp))),
              "iou mean {} \n".format(np.array(iou_tmp).mean()))
        mse_tmp = []
        iou_tmp = []
        del mse_tmp
        del iou_tmp
```

Comment: You could start my giving us the code *exactly* as it is written.  The indentation of the code above is not legal Python.  And code should have triple backquotes on the line before it and the line after it.

Comment: I am sorry, I must have formatted it in the question itself.  Let me fix it. It is exactly what I am running except for formatting. I fixed also the backquotes, Thank you for pointing that out. I am not very familiar with asking questions here.